# Convert cst to pst in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a datetime in a google data base that is in cst.  I would like to convert it to pst.

Queries such as

`SELECT DATETIME("2008-12-25 15:30:00+07","America/Los_Angeles") as date;`

seem to assume that the starting date is in UTC.  How can I convert if the starting date is in cst?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert time in Bigquery regardless of what your starting date to a `DATETIME` in a specific [timezone](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#time_zones):

```
SELECT DATETIME("2008-12-25 15:30:00-06" ,"PST8PDT") as date;
```

Output:
[image]